# SELECT RANGE 1 EM 1 HORA - POSTGRESQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

**OBJETIVO**

Gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` dentro de um range de **1 hora em 1 hora**

**DATA TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    t_id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    time   TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, '2019-10-28 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, '2019-10-28 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, '2019-10-28 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, '2019-10-28 09:30:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, '2019-10-28 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, '2019-10-28 10:30:00');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    t_id,
    MIN(time)
FROM
    t
WHERE
    date_trunc('day', time) = current_date
GROUP BY
    t_id,
    date_trunc('hour', time)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
t_id    min
4   2019-10-28 09:30:00
5   2019-10-28 10:30:00
1   2019-10-28 08:00:00
2   2019-10-28 08:30:00
3   2019-10-28 09:00:00
6   2019-10-28 10:00:00
```

**OUTPUT ESPERADO**

```
t_id    min
1   2019-10-28 08:00:00
3   2019-10-28 09:00:00
5   2019-10-28 10:00:00
```

**OBS: PERGUNTA REFORMULADA**

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fe435/1/0)

Comment: Pelo seu exemplo de dados e resultado esperado, poderia usar where extract('minute' from time) = 0 que resolve.

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado amigo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você chegou bem perto de resolver o problema, veja só:

```
SELECT t_id, time FROM t WHERE date_trunc('hour',time) = time;
```

Saída:

```
| t_id |                 time |
|------|----------------------|
|    1 | 2019-10-28T08:00:00Z |
|    3 | 2019-10-28T09:00:00Z |
|    5 | 2019-10-28T10:00:00Z |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fe435/32)

Comment: Em uma linha resolveu o problema rsrs' muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isto que está querendo:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(
        (SELECT min(date_trunc('hour', time)) FROM t)::timestamp, 
        (SELECT max(date_trunc('hour', time)) FROM t)::timestamp, 
        '1 hour'::interval);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Apenas preste atenção na nomenclatura pois RANGE é um tipo de dado do PostgreSQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: Opa, nao sabia disso, obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Essa consulta pode retornar registros inexistentes na tabela `t`, veja só: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f2b34e/1

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele queria os timestamps de hora em hora sem a necessidade de serem registros de sua tabela, apenas o horário de início e fim sendo o menor e maior horário existente na tabela. Mas possa ter deduzido errado.